# highlight datagridview row if row/column cell is empty (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview which highlights itself if the cell has no value in it, at the moment it only works for one cell, i want add 2 more cells, so if 3 cells have no value in it then highlight row.

the code at the moment:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    For i As Integer = 1 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("DateFixed1").Value = ("") Then
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("DateFixed1").Style.ForeColor = Color.Black
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.cells
            If cell.Value = ("") 
            Then
               cell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black
               row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed
            End If
        Next
Next
```

Comment: this is giving an error of 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid'. Should there not be another code for the 2 other cells.